# mySQL how to count this item id

Tags: mysql

I have a table

Table item kit

```
 item_kit_id    item_id    
 =======================
 1              1
 1              1
 1              2
 2              2
 2              237
```

how to display result

```
 item_kit_id    item_id    count  
 ===============================
 1              1          2
 1              2          1
 2              2          1
 2              237        1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use group by with both column its return your expected result

```
SELECT item_kit_id,item_id,count(*) 
FROM kit
GROUP BY item_kit_id,item_id;
```

For more know about [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query-

```
select item_kit_id, item_id, count(item_id) as count 
from item_kit 
group by item_kit_id, item_id;
```